# can't change python path and configure for anaconda

Tags: python, bash, macos, anaconda, dotfiles

I would like to create conda virutal environments and unable to do so probably due to the Python path.

I have tried to edit the .bash_profile and set the PATH for python but changes are not getting reflected and path remains same.

```sh
$ which python
/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin/python

$ echo $PATH
/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin:/Users/myusername/anaconda3/condabin:/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Here is my `.bash_profile`

```
Simplified dotfile for video recordings

# Load dotfiles:
for file in ~/.{bash_prompt,aliases,private}; do
    [ -r "$file" ] && [ -f "$file" ] && source "$file";
done;
unset file;

#Git auto-complete
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
    source ~/.git-completion.bash
fi

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Homebrew path
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
# added by Anaconda3 2019.07 installer
```

I also use aliases like `python=python3` and `pip=pip3`

Comment: "unable to do so probably due to the python path." Could you maybe include what the actual problem is, you are only presenting your setup in your question, but no error or similar of what is actually not working

Comment: This might help. From `man bash`: `~/.bash_profile`: The personal initialization file, executed for **login shells**

Comment: # To activate this environment, use
#
#     $ conda activate my_app
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use
#
#     $ conda deactivate

 ~
**$ source activate my_app**
In this case in have activated the virual environment but it hasn't started probably due to PATH of python

Comment: 1. Please add these info to your question, not as comments. 2. "it haven't started probably due to PATH of python" is again not very informative. What does "havn't started probably' mean and what makes you think that it didn't

Comment: You said you had an alias for pip3. Did you use pip3?  If you're running Anaconda you should use conda instead of pip.

Answer (score 1):

conda comes with its own python/pip and manipulates your environment variables during activation accordingly by doing `source /path/to/conda/bin/activate`. During anaconda/miniconda installation you can decide for either python2 or 3. Independent of this, environments can have their own python installation instead of using the conda base env. `conda create -y -n py2 python=2` `conda create -y -n py3 python=3`, respectively. You'd  better not try to mess with $PATH and PYTHONPATH or PYTHONUSERBASE by yourself.

Here is code for a clean re-installaion of miniconda and the whole 3GB anaconda setup. In case you just need single tools for your work, you can lookup for them via [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org) and save a lot of storage space.

```sh
wget -q -O miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash miniconda.sh -b -f -p /install/path
source /install/path/bin/activate
conda install -c anaconda anaconda
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a virtual environment using conda just type:

```sh
conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

say I wanted to create a virtual environment to run python version 3.7.3. I name the environment py37. I type:

```sh
conda create -n py37 python=3.7 anaconda
```